# Can XDomainRequest be used to make same-origin requests?

Tags: internet-explorer, xdomainrequest

What happens if you use IE8/9's XDomainRequest object to make a same-origin request? Does the request succeed? If so, is it [limited in the same ways](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/05/13/xdomainrequest-restrictions-limitations-and-workarounds.aspx) as cross-origin requests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`XDomainRequest` seems to always attach an `Origin` header to requests it sends, making it appear as if they are cross-origin, even if they are not.  So, if a same-origin request is made to a server using `XDomainRequest`, the request will fail if the server doesn't include Access-Control-Allow-Origin among its response headers.  I verified this myself just now.  The  ability to set headers would be part of the transport's `prototype`, so methods like `setRequestHeader` are also still missing, regardless of the ultimate destination.